# Can I use Data Annotations to perform a Cascade Delete with Entity Framework 4.1 RC?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

When using data annotations with EF4.1 RC is there an annotation to cause cascade deletes?

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Using this model the constraint generated is:

```
ALTER TABLE [Product] ADD CONSTRAINT [Product_Category] 
FOREIGN KEY ([Category_Id]) REFERENCES [Categorys]([Id]) 
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

If not how is it achieved?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Putting required on the Product table Category relationship field solves this

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]  //<======= Forces Cascade delete
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What gets deleted upon deletion of what?

Comment: Searching for `ef core foreign key annotation cascade delete` found nothing. Your comment worked as expected. Thanks

Comment: @ShimmyWeitzhandler Product requires Category, so if Category is deleted, product vanishes together with it I guess

Answer (score 51):

I like to turn off cascade delete by default (by removing the `OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention`)

I was then hoping to add them back in via annotations, but was surprised that EF doesn't include a `CascadeDeleteAttribute`.

After spending way too long working around EF's ridiculous internal accessor levels, the code in this gist adds a convention that allows attributes to be used: https://gist.github.com/tystol/20b07bd4e0043d43faff

To use, just stick the `[CascadeDelete]` on either end of the navigation properties for the relationship, and add the convention in your DbContext's OnModeCreating callback. eg:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<CascadeDeleteAttributeConvention>();
}
```

And in your model:

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [CascadeDelete]
    public List<BlogPostComment> Comments { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: This is better than the chosen answer because the Requiered attribute imples a not-nullable foreign key. And it works with EF 6. Thanks!

Comment: Great solution, also, please note that the Convention class should be added to the `modelBuilder.Conventions` in `OnModelCreating` method.

Comment: This only seems to work on [Required] relationships, so in my case I modified CascadeDeleteAttribute to inherit from RequiredAttribute for clarity

Answer (score 3):

Not sure on Data Annotations, but you can add it in the database by modifying the actual relationship.

Looks like the answer is no for data annotations:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/394821ae-ab28-4b3f-b554-184a6d1ba72d/

This question appears to show how to do it with the fluent syntax, but not sure if that applies for 4.1 RC 
[EF 4.1 RC: Weird Cascade Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402964/ef-4-1-rc-weird-cascade-delete)

Answer (score 3):

As an additional example to [Tyson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33276901/387023), I use the `[CascadeDelete]` attribute like follows in an entity, which successfully adds the "Cascade" delete rule to the `Parent`-`Child` relation.

```
public class Child
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    [SkipTracking]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [CascadeDelete]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
}
```