# Entity Framework Data Annotations equivalent of .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

Tags: data-annotations, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I'm currently using EF Code First 4.3 with migrations enabled, but automatic migrations disabled.

My question is simple, is there a data annotations equivalent of the model configuration .WillCascadeOnDelete(false)

I would like to decorate my class so that the foreign key relationships do NOT trigger a cascading delete.

Code sample:

```
public class Container
{
    public int ContainerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Output> Outputs { get; set; }
}

public class Output
{
    public int ContainerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Container Container { get; set; }

    public int OutputTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual OutputType OutputType { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}  

public class OutputType 
{
    public int OutputTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I Would like to do something like this:

```
public class Output
{
    [CascadeOnDelete(false)]   
    public int ContainerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Container Container { get; set; }

    [CascadeOnDelete(false)]    
    public int OutputTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual OutputType OutputType { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

This way i would be able to scaffold the migration correctly. which scaffolds the foreign key relationships to be cascade deleted at the moment.

Any ideas, other than using Model Configuration?

Comment: Have the same question. Found how to enable it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33276901/4625305), but what I want is to disable it only for one relationship.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No there is no such equivalent. You must use fluent API to remove cascade delete selectively or you must remove `OneToManyCascadeDelete` convention to remove it globally.

Comment: will removing OneToManyCascadeDelete convention, remove convention even if you add annotations like [Required] to a foreign key?

Comment: Cascade delete should be used only for relations which are required and removing this convention will break it. Optional are just set to null.

Comment: In case of using OneToManyCascadeDelete = false, how would I enable cascade delete selectively with data annotations?

Comment: There's no built in equivalent, but with EF 6 you can write your own attribute and convention (with a bit of reflection based invoking of EF's internal members). See my answer here, which disables the default cascade and uses attributes to opt back in. You could always do the inverse with some small tweaks to the convention code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33276901/505457

Answer (score 2):

Create a mapping class (the fluent syntax) and use the code below:

```
// add relationships "Post" and "User" to a "Comment" entity
this.HasRequired(t => t.Post)
    .WithMany(t => t.Comments)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.PostID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // <---

this.HasOptional(t => t.User)
    .WithMany(t => t.Comments)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); // <---
```

Here's a [nice post](http://www.remondo.net/code-first-fluent-api-entity-type-configuration/) on how to set up fluent mappings if you need more info.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the FK property nullable can prevent cascade delete from happening:

```cs
public int? OutputTypeID { get; set; }
```