# Delete item from database but not other item related to this

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I have this in my Article class:

```
    public int GalleryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Gallery Gallery { get; set; }
```

and this is my gallery class:

```
public class Gallery
{

    public int GalleryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}
```

when I delete gallery by this in repository:

```
    public virtual void Delete(int id)
    {
        T entity = dbset.Find(id);
        dbset.Remove(entity);
        dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I deleted article too but that isn´t what I want. I want to keep article (just maybe set galleryId to 0 a and gallery to null. Thanks

Comment: How does your question relate to ASP.NET MVC3? It looks more like you are asking about how to use some ORM (which by the way you haven't specified in your question). Is it EF or something? Please use proper tags.

Comment: I am sorry, yes it´s EF.

Answer (score 1):

In your artical make the foreign key nullable

```
public int? GalleryID { get; set; }
```

On delete of the gallery, you need to clear its article collection

```
public void DeleteGallery(int id)
{
    var entity = dataContext.Galleries
                .Include(e => e.Articles)  // include your child object collection
                .First(e => e.Id == id);

    dataContext.Galleries.Articles.Clear();  // this removes the reference to the parent
    dataContext.Galleries.Remove(entity);

    dataContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

see here [EF 4.1 RC: Weird Cascade Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402964/ef-4-1-rc-weird-cascade-delete)

Comment: This might help but now I have this problem: "The primary key value cannot be deleted because references to this key still exist. [ Foreign key constraint name = FK_Articles_Galleries_GalleryID ]"

Comment: are you using code first fluent api? how are you specifying the FK?

Comment: For now code in classes was just enough. Can you help me with what I shoudl add to ´protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)´ ?

Comment: you will need to remove the parent child relationship from the child, see above